# Rotation of a unit vector at a random point iby an angle along Y axis in 3D space

Tags: vb.net, vector, rotation, rotational-matrices

I had attached also the schematic to depict my question.

1. I need to rotate the vector V with the base point P by an angle and find the new vector V'.
2. The rotation axis is say for is about a local y axis at point P (which is parallel to global Y axis)
3. Subsequently, I need to rotate the initial vector V about x axis which is parallel to global Y axis.

The main reason for the rotation is to find the new vector V' at point P. Both the rotations are independent and each of the rotation provides a new V'. I'm programming this in VB.net and output is a double() of new vector V'.

[image: e]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: I haven't started with the coding yet. I tried to read from online that I need to transform point P to origin, multiply with the rotation matrix for rotation along Y axis and transfer back to point P from origin. I don't have a clue where to start as it does not mention about the vector V. That's where I'm confussed.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the two rotations independently (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)). The base point does not play any role in this because it is just a constant offset that never changes. If I got your description right, you want the following:

```
//rotation about y-axis
iAfterRot1 = cos(phi1) * i + sin(phi1) * k
jAfterRot1 = j 
kAfterRot1 = -sin(phi1) * i + cos(phi) * k

//rotation about x-axis
iAfterRot2 = iAfterRot1
jAfterRot2 = cos(phi2) * jAfterRot1 - sin(phi2) * kAfterRot1
kAfterRot2 = sin(phi2) * jAfterRot1 + cos(phi2) * kAfterRot1
```

Comment: Hi Nico, I tried to follow your steps, here are the results which I acheived